# Getting ViewModel Values from MVC Kendo Grid using Javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am initializing a kendo grid like this:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<EPSModels.Models.SuretyViewModel>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.SuretyName);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Address);
        columns.Bound(c => c.City);
        columns.Bound(c => c.State);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ZipCode);
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit().Text(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "fa fa-pencil", @style = "margin-right:15px" }); command.Destroy().Text(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "fa fa-trash-o" }); }).Title("Actions").Width("180px");
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
    .Pageable(pager => pager.Input(true).PageSizes(true).PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 25, 50, 100 }).PreviousNext(true).Numeric(false).Info(true))
    .Sortable(sortable => sortable.AllowUnsort(true).SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn))
    .Resizable(resizable => resizable.Columns(true))
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .Scrollable(scroll => scroll.Height(300))
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("SuretyEditor").Window(w => w.Title("Add/Edit Surety").Width(650)))
    .Events(e => { e.DataBound("OnDataBound"); e.Edit("onEdit"); })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add Surety"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
            .Sort(sort => sort.Add("CreatedDate").Descending())
    .Events(events => events.Error("grid_error"))
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.SuretyId);           
        })
    .Create(update => update.Action("CreateSurety", "Bonds"))
    .Destroy(update => update.Action("DeleteSurety", "Bonds"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateSurety", "Bonds"))
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetSureties", "Bonds").Data("GetSuretyNameForFilter"))
    ))
```

The code for the popup/editor template is like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, new {@class = "control-label col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"})
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-5">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State, new SelectList(
                (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["States"],
                "Value",
                "Text",
                Model.State), new { id = "ddlStates", @style = "min-width:172px;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State)
        </div>
```

How can I access the Model.State property in Javascript ? I have tried the following to no avail:

alert(@Model.State);

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var state = document.getElementById("ddlStates");
alert(state[state.selectedIndex].value);
</script>
```

Any hints or ideas would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you have simple values in your Model and you want to access it with JS, you can simply put them in a Hidden input's value and use Jquery to read the value from it.
If you have more complex view model you can use a code like below to convert your entire viewmodel to a JavaScript object and then use it as like a json object:

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```